# R: how to use regex to substitute an element appeared multiple time by single one of them

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have:

```
txt= 'finance . . . . . lottery ticket . . . community'
```

trying to get:

```
txt2 = 'finance.lottery ticket.community'
```

but the following didn't work:

```
gsub('[[:punct:]]{2,}','',txt)
```

Did I do anything wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Try `gsub(' *([[:punct:]] *)+','.',txt)`

Comment: @horcrux thanks! just realized I didn't include the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are spaces between `.` in your text, you need to include that in your regex as well:

```
gsub('(\\s?[[:punct:]]\\s?){2,}','.',txt)
# [1] "finance.lottery ticket.community"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
 gsub('(\\s*[.]\\s*)+','.',txt)
 #[1] "finance.lottery ticket.community"
```